# What does the warning mean?

Tags: ocaml

```
# let [x;y;z] = [1;2;3];;
Warning P: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
[]
val x : int = 1
val y : int = 2
val z : int = 3
# x;;
- : int = 1
# y;;
- : int = 2
# z;;
- : int = 3
```

It seems the value declaration works quite well, what is the warning actually trying to tell?

Answer (score 5):

The pattern `[x; y; z]` doesn't match all possible values of its type. In general, you want to avoid patterns like this--it means there are cases where your code will fail. In this particular case (if you never change the code) there's no problem because the pattern is matched against a constant value. But the compiler is warning you anyway, just in case. Perhaps it figures you might change the constant list later.

It would be nice to have a way to disable the warning for cases like this, I have to say.

The idiomatic way to write this (with no warning) is:

```
let x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
```

In this case, the pattern (`x, y, z`) *does* match all possible values of its type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, any expression binding is translated at compile time into a pattern match, since it is possible to wrie a pattern on the left side of the binding sign `=`. So it's pretty much as if you wrote:

```
let x,y,z = 
    let v =  [1;2;3] in
    match v with
      | [x;y;z] -> x,y,z
```

This a bit convoluted, but the code which is typechecked could resemble a little to the above<sup>[1]</sup>. In this setting, you can see perhaps a bit better that the pattern matching mechanism is the same whether you use a simple binding expression or a full fledged `match ... with` expression. In both cases, the typechecker will infer from the type of the expression if there are cases which are missed by the pattern match, and warn you about them. For `list` pattern matches, indeed the value `[]` is a possibility.

---

<sub>[1]: I say "could" , because I believe that actually the `match ... with`  syntactic form is also transformed to another form, which is probably closer to the `function` form (ie. `function [x;y;z] -> ...` in your case).</sub>

Comment: @JeffreyScofield did answer your question already, so consider this one as providing details about pattern matching.